# Overriding Backbone Collection Add Error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following Backbone Collection. **My problem is when I do car.get("brand"), I get undefined.**

The brand attribute is there. I know because when I do console.log(car), I can see it. It's as if the .get property doesn't exist on the car object. But that is impossible because I place my Car Model script, before my Cars Collection script.

So isDupe is failing as a result. Not even sure if this.any is being called. **But 100% .get is not there!** Help!

```
var Cars = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Car,
add: function(object) {
        var car = new Car(object);

        var isDupe = false;

        isDupe = this.any(function(_car) { 
            return _car.get("brand") === car.get("brand");
        });

        console.log("isDupe: " + isDupe);

        if (isDupe) {
            return false;
        }

        Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, car);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My version of this would look something similar to this:

```
Car = Backbone.Model.extend({

  eql: function(other) {
    return this.get('brand') == other.get('brand');
  }

});

CarList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: Car,

  add: function(newCar) {
     isDupe = this.any(function(car) {
       return car.eql(newCar);
     });
     if (isDupe) return;
     Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, newCar);
  }

});
```

Comment: I want to say thank you for all your help here. I'm 2 levels deep in asynchronous calls and I think things just don't work as expected that far down. I'll re-evaluate this during a level 1 workflow.

Comment: Two levels deep in asynch seems a bad app architecture smell to me.  I work on a team building a pretty sizable app and we are never two levels deep.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't control the returning json data. The 2nd async call depends on data returned in the 1st. Any suggestions?